# Getting string from spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'd like to get the string that the user select from a spinner menu. It should get the string after the user select one of them and saved that string in a new variable.
I had such a code that the new variable only could take the value of the default and it can not update what the user selected.

The strings are

```
String[] models={"Model 1" , "Model 2" };
```

and my onCreate method looks like follow:

```
Spinner spinModel=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerModel);
spinModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
//creamos el spinner con las cadenas de modelos almacenadas en la variable items
ArrayAdapter<String> aa= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,models);
//Decimos como debe mostrar este elemento
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//editamos el spinner
spinModel.setAdapter(aa);
    //I TRIED THIS FUNCTION
model = spinModel.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Thank you very much to everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had such a code that the new variable only could take the value of
>   the default and it can not update what the user selected.

You need to assign `OnItemSelectedListener` for your `Spinner` and assign selectedItem in `OnItemSelected` method. It will make a trick.

```
spinModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                                   long id) {
            model = spinModel.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
    });
```

Comment: Then I guess it works like a button. Ok! thank you very much, I'll try!!